# Fetching an image from Server

Tags: android, web-services, soap

Here is my code to fetch an image from a server location into a web service folder `"web content"`.

```
// imports removed

public class WebService {

    public int writeToFileImage(int a) throws IOException{

        File file =new File("sdcard/myImage.jpg");
        file.createNewFile();

        URL u = new URL("http://172.29.26.40:8080/ExampleService/demo.jpg"); 
        URLConnection uc = u.openConnection(); 
        uc.connect(); 
        InputStream in = uc.getInputStream(); 
        FileOutputStream out;
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        final int BUF_SIZE = 1 << 8; 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE]; 
        int bytesRead = -1; 
        while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > -1) { 
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
        } 
        in.close();
        out.close(); 
        return a;
    }
}
```

But i am getting an exception:

```
SOAP Response Envelope
- <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
- <soapenv:Body>
- <soapenv:Fault>
  <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode> 
  <faultstring>java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect</faultstring> 
- <detail>
  <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">01HW040207</ns1:hostname> 
  </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: have you tried to access this URL with your web browser? maybe the resource is simply not available? because I can't reach it from here...

Comment: Hope you are clear in your description about what you want to do. From your code it looks like you want to fetch the image from a server into your device sdcard. Generally you would not make port 8080 public. However make sure that it is accessible from your emulator. The terms SOAP, WebService should be unrelated to this simple task of downloading an image to a device.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is pretty old but
there's a great image downloader library at github

[Android Image Loder](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

it works perfectly, also it includes cache ( where you can also turned off ) multi task download and etc.

cheers
hope this helps...